# Are we proud of our "Greatest Hits"?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I learned about the ["Greatest Hits" feature](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/) for StackExchange sites.   Looking over our [top questions](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits), I see many great answers and often multiple answers per question.  Not surprisingly, many of these questions are from the earliest days of the site.  (It takes time for Google to pick up a question and for people to discover the answers.)  At any rate, we've changed since then so I'm wondering if we are proud of those questions and answers, or if we should look into editing them to knock them into shape.

All of which is to say, I looked over the first page of questions and found a lot to be proud of and nothing in particular I felt needed to be improved.  What do you think about our earlier, popular questions?